# padding file to 4 byte boundary

Tags: linux, bash, shell

In linux bash, how can we concatenate files with padding on 4-byte boundary. I have 3 files a.txt, b.txt, c.txt, and want to concatenate them to create d.txt, each element file is started on 4-byte boundary.

```
a.txt: 1 byte
b.txt: 2 bytes
c.txt: 4 bytes

d.txt should be
0-3: a.txt
4-7: b.txt
8-11: c.txt
```

Any suggestions are appreciated. 
Thanks and Best Regards,
Dien

Comment: Do these files only have one line each or is `a.txt` (for example) 100 lines of one character each?

Comment: Hi Paxdiablo, each member file is binary file too

Comment: Thank everyone for taking to time answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for i in {a..c}.txt
do
    cat $i
    head -c $(((4-$(stat -c %s $i)%4)%4)) /dev/zero
done >d.txt
```

Comment: You could do the redirection after the for: `for ... done > d.txt`.

Comment: +1: this is nice, but [a-c].txt is a bit dangerous if one of the files does not exist.  It might be better to use {a,b,c}.txt to run the loop on the nonextant file and allow cat to generate an error.

Comment: For myself, nice answer, almost the best so far, so +1. Maybe a problem if the file changes between `cat` and `stat`, so we could do `size=$(cat $i | tee -a d.txt | wc -c)` to get the size at the same time as `cat`.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you wish to pad with spaces, one relatively simple solution is:

```
perl -wpE 'BEGIN{ $/ = \4 } print " " x ( 4 - length )
    if length != 4' a.txt b.txt c.txt > d.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you need zero-byte padding, you can use `head` with both the actual files and `/dev/zero` (to get padding). First set up some test files:

```
pax> echo -n 1 >a.txt ; echo -n 12 >b.txt ; echo -n 1234 >c.txt
```

Then the following code will give you what you want.

```
pax> ( head -c1 a.txt ; head -c3 /dev/zero ;
       head -c2 b.txt ; head -c2 /dev/zero ;
       head -c4 c.txt ) | od -xcb
0000000    0031    0000    3231    0000    3231    3433
          1  \0  \0  \0   1   2  \0  \0   1   2   3   4
        061 000 000 000 061 062 000 000 061 062 063 064
0000014
```

You can see the padding has been placed in the output stream. So a script to do this is as simple as:

```
( head -c1 a.txt ; head -c3 /dev/zero )  >d.txt
( head -c2 b.txt ; head -c2 /dev/zero ) >>d.txt
( head -c4 c.txt                      ) >>d.txt
```

Or, if you don't really *care* what goes into the padding area, you can use a one-liner like:

```
cat [abc].txt | sed 's/^\(.\)\(..\)/\1___\2__/' >d.txt
```

This will produce a file containing:

```
1___12__1234
```